# Left Mouse Button Click in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a program that clicks on a button in my web browser.

The current code:

```
set sh=createobject("wscript.shell")
sh.SendKeys "{Click, 669 , 674}"
wscript.sleep 100
sh.sendkeys "{Click, 669 , 674}"
```

---

I think there is something wrong with the command for the left mouse button.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

[`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) can only send *keystrokes*.

Check out [`nircmd`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (specifically the `sendmouse` command) or another third-party utility.

Comment: i tried i with the sendmouse command, but i don't know how to write this. could you maybe try to do it?

Comment: Update your question with what you're trying and I'll take a look.